# Junit4 and TestNG in one project with Maven with inheritance

Tags: java, maven, junit, testng

I have the same problem as [Junit4 and TestNG in one project with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238017/junit4-and-testng-in-one-project-with-maven) but I still have issues.
I created simple project where I need to use junit4 and testng
Here is root pom:

```xml
    <groupId>com.dimas.testmodule</groupId>
            <artifactId>TheParent</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.001</version>
            <name>TheParent</name>
            <packaging>pom</packaging>

            <properties>
                <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
                <spring.scope>test</spring.scope>
                <maven.surefire.plugin.version>2.9</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.7</version> 
                       <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
        ...etc
                </dependencies>

            <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <target>1.6</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

            <profiles>
                <profile>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <activation>
                        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                    </activation>
                    <modules>
                        <module>JUnitOnly</module>
                        <module>TestNGOnly</module>
                        <module>testmodule</module>
                    </modules>
                    <build>
                        <plugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                                <configuration>
                                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
<excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*NGTest.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                                </configuration>
                            </plugin>
                        </plugins>
                    </build>
                </profile>

                <profile>
                    <id>testNGonly</id>
                    <modules>
                        <module>JUnitOnly</module>
                        <module>TestNGOnly</module>
                        <module>testmodule</module>
                    </modules>

                    <build>
                        <plugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                                <configuration>
                                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*NGTest.java</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </configuration>
                            </plugin>
                        </plugins>
                    </build>
                </profile>
            </profiles>
```

modules JUnitOnly and TestModule just inherits and do not overrite any properties. And here are TestNgOnly

```xml
<groupId>com.dimas.testmodule.testngonly</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestNGOnly</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.001</version>
    <name>testngonly</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.dimas.testmodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>TheParent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.001</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>testNGtest</id>  
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>
                                    <!--test/resources/my-testng.xml-->
                                    src\test\resources\my-testng.xml
                                </suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Well I need to ignore testng tests for default profile and launch only testng tests for profile testNGOnly.

Comment: What `issues` do you have?  testng tests are running in the `testmodule` for the `default` profile?  Or tests are running in `testNGOnly`?  If latter, why include that module in the `default` profile?

Comment: testmodule - contains and junit and testng tests. TestNgOnly module  contatins only testng tests. Junit module contains only junit tests. When I start tetsNGOnly profile only testng tests must be launched. When I start deafult profile only junit tests must be launched.

Comment: I created a skeletal multi-module project illustrating this use case [here](https://github.com/maruhgar/mvn-examples/tree/master/mixtestsmultimodule).  See if this solves your problem.  I can detail it as answer, if so.

Comment: thanx a lot. Looks like it what I need. I just add configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration> to your code and all start to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three modules - `junit`, `testng` and `mixed`.

The default profile should execute only junit tests - i.e. run `junit` module and run junit tests of `mixed` module.   `testNG` profile should execute only testNG tests - i.e. run `testNG` module and run testNG tests of `mixed` module.

The way profiles work in maven, it is not possible to `exclude` a module in a profile. However, there is no need to build a module which is not required.

Thus, in default profile, have modules `junit` and `mixed`.

In testNG profile, add module `testNG`.

Following maven best practice, define `<dependencies>` in the parent pom within `<dependencyManagement>`.  This allows us to only use junit dependency in `junit` module and testNG dependency in `testNG` module.

There is nothing common about `surefire` configuration across the three modules and as such not required to be specified in parent pom.

Since it not required to run junit tests in `testNG` profile, add a plugin configuration to `skipTests` in `testNG` profile for `junit` module.

Configure the `mixed` pom using the tip in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1238637/254643) for the [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238017/junit4-and-testng-in-one-project-with-maven) SO question. This gets tricky since surefire needs to use junit or testng runner based on the profile.

I have incorporated the above suggestions in a sample project [here](https://github.com/maruhgar/mvn-examples/tree/master/mixtestsmultimodule).