# TestNG tests don't run in Maven Project alongside JUnit4 projects

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven-3, testng, junit4

This is a project that uses both TestNG and JUnit4. I am not able to run the TestNG test suite for any reason. The error stack trace is given below.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Exception in thread "ThreadedStreamConsumer" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.ap
ache.maven.surefire.report.StackTraceWriter.getThrowable()Ljava/lang/Throwable;
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.report.XMLReporter.writeTestProblems(XMLRep
orter.java:272)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.report.XMLReporter.testFailed(XMLReporter.j
ava:249)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.report.MulticastingReporter.testFailed(Mult
icastingReporter.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.report.TestSetRunListener.testFailed(TestSe
tRunListener.java:157)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient.consu
meLine(ForkClient.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ThreadedStreamCo
nsumer$Pumper.run(ThreadedStreamConsumer.java:67)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

My pom set up is given below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org /2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <prerequisites>
    <maven>3.0.4</maven>
 </prerequisites>
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <surefire.version>2.13</surefire.version>
 </properties>
 <parent>
  <groupId>com.google</groupId>
  <artifactId>google</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.google.testing</groupId>
 <artifactId>test-libraries-for-java</artifactId>
 <version>1.2</version>

 <profiles>
  <profile>
  <id>junit4-only</id>
  <build>
   <finalName>tl4j</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>junit4-only-${project.version}</classifier>
              <includes>
                <include>**/junit4/*</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>

<profile>
  <id>agnostic</id>
  <build>
   <finalName>tl4j</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>agnostic-${project.version}</classifier>
              <includes>
                <include>**/common/testing/*.class</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>

 <profile>
  <id>junit4</id>
  <build>
    <finalName>tl4j</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>junit4-${project.version}</classifier>
              <includes>
                <include>**/common/testing/*.class</include>
                <include>**/junit4/*</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>

<profile>
   <id>testng</id>
   <build>
       <finalName>tl4j</finalName>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>jar</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <classifier>testng-${project.version}</classifier>
                           <includes>
                               <include>**/common/testing/*.class</include>
                               <include>**/testng/*</include>
                           </includes>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
  </profile>
  <profile>
      <id>testng-only</id>
      <build>
          <finalName>tl4j</finalName>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <phase>package</phase>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>jar</goal>
                          </goals>
                          <configuration>
                              <classifier>testng-${project.version}</classifier>
                              <includes>
                                 <include>**/testng/*</include>
                              </includes>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.15</version>
      <type>maven-plugin</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies> 
<build>
<!--  <finalName>tl4j</finalName>       -->
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target-eclipse/classes</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>deploy</id>
          <phase>deploy</phase>
          <configuration>
            <tasks>
              <echo
                message="Please follow directions at doc/HOW_TO_RELEASE.txt to make the release" />
            </tasks>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
          </dependency>
           <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
             <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
             <version>${surefire.version}</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
      <configuration>
        <show>private</show>
        <nohelp>true</nohelp>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

My unit test

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TearDownTestCaseTest {

  @Test
  public void assertTrue() {
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

Funny thing is that if I configure this test to run as JUnit 3 test case, it works, but not JUnit 4.x or Testng.

Comment: have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238017/junit4-and-testng-in-one-project-with-maven/1238637#1238637

Comment: I don't have a default includes or excludes. Each profile configures its own includes so there should not be any overriding.